# How to switch from XIB to Storyboard?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, mapkit, xib

I'm using this project: http://maybelost.com/2011/01/a-basic-mapview-and-annotation-tutorial/ as a base and working on by adding annotations and now I'd like to add tabs.

I want to work with Storyboard as I think it simplifies the whole tab bar controller experience but every time i change the appdelegate class and do everything specified to change to storyboard the project won't run. The app simulates but without running the code or showing the tab bar. Only a map appears.

Any help?

edit// I was using this doc to help me: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/index.html and also previous stackoverflow answers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following

1. Specified the class name for the view controller in interface builder (main storyboard)?
2. do a clean build before running the app on simulator.
3. delete the previously installed app (old code) on simulator.
4. Also try closing the Xcode project and re-opening.

Comment: yes I have and it still doesn't work. I specify the main interface to be storyboard in the targets>general>deployment info part and doesn't work but when back to the xib file it works fine :/

Comment: What I meant was, Main Storyboard -> Select the ViewController (which has the mapview control) -> Navigate to Attributes Inspector (IB) -> Specify the class (under custom class).

Comment: yes I understand, and I did that but still nothing.